# URL images sometimes load sometimes not vue js

Tags: css, image, vue.js, url, rendering

I have this problem in which i generate images by classical foreach method.

```
          <div v-for="messageGroup in conversation" class="messagegroup" :class="{ recieved: messageGroup.recieved }">
        <div v-if="messageGroup.recieved" class="iconcontainer">
          <div class="iconcontainerinner">
            <img class='usericoncontacts' :src="selectedContact.userPhotoURL" alt="">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="textmessages" :class="{ recieved: messageGroup.recieved }">
          <div class="message" v-for="message in messageGroup.messages">
            <span>{{ message }}</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

The images then have it's source at Google repo which looks for an example like this

[image: Google link]

The images then either [image: load] or sometimes don't like [image: this]

My guess is that it has something to do with vue rendering.
Thanks in advance

Comment: i dont understand the request?

Comment: https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-lPfsjKEPg0U/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/AMZuucnwdatbhvxOJ1PR8v656ca57XH-Cg/photo.jpg